# Create un unbalanced polyhedron dice

Tags: dice

I need a dice with a strange number of faces (Eg. $7,9,11,13,14$) that is totally unbalanced (each side has a different area), but with the ratio of the largest and smallest face area not too big (say between $2$ and $3$). How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Start with a very regular one and perturbate the vertices.

Comment: You could make a prism - like a cylinder, but the cylinder's curved side is replaced by a sequence of flat sides

Comment: Unless you double the number of faces (with the numbers on the faces also duplicated), it may be difficult to see which face is "up" when a particular face is down